# Where is the $1/2$ lost in Fourier transform?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

From an old notebook, I found a question mark (not known existing how many years) about a contradition between the integral form and the original exponential decaying function $f(t)$.

$$
f(t)=\begin{cases}
    e^{-bt},&  t\ge 0\\
    0         & t<0
\end{cases}
$$
where $b>0$ and $f(0)=1$. The Fourier transform of $f(t)$ is
$$
\mathcal{F}[f(t)](\omega)=\frac{1}{j\omega+b},
$$

But if $f(t)$ is recovered by inverse transform from $F(\omega)$
\begin{align}
f(t)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j\omega+b}e^{j\omega t}\mathrm d\omega\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{b\cos{\omega t}+\omega\sin{\omega t}}{\omega^2+b^2}\mathrm d\omega\\
&=\begin{cases}
    0 & \text{ for } t<0 \text{ (this integral is a bit complexed to solve) }\\
    \frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\arctan\frac{\omega}{b}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}=\frac12 & \text{ for } t=0\\
    e^{-bt} & \text{ for } t>0
\end{cases}
\end{align}

where in the second case $t=0$, $f(t)$ becomes only $\frac12\ne e^{-bt}|_{t=0}=1$.

Where in the steps lost the other half?

Comment: Think about the domain of the Fourier transform.   What kind of object does it act on?

Comment: Sorry not get the point. Please...

Comment: Do you have an answer to the question I asked?  What kind of object does the FT act on?

Comment: The time domain but with $u(t)$, right? Or I didn't get what object means?

Comment: No, not quite.  The FT acts on *functions*.  You feed it a function, and it spits out another function.   Typically, the FT is initially defined on the space $L^1$ of Lebesgue integrable "functions", but the objects in $L^1$ are not *quite* functions (in the sense that they aren't pointwise defined)---they are *equivalence classes* of functions.  Two functions $f$ and $g$ are representatives of the same equivalence class if $\int |f-g| = 0$.  In this space, the two functions you have (which differ only at zero) are representatives of the same object.

Comment: Do you mean $\delta(x)$ function or by Stone–Weierstrass TH? Sorry I am not a real mathematician but an eager to learn physist.

Comment: No.  I am not talking about Stone-Weierstrass.  I am talking about the definition of an $L^1$ "function".  Two pointwise-defined functions which differ only on a set of measure zero will have the same FT, because the FT doesn't "see" the difference between those two functions.  Instead, which if I take your function and redefine it so that $f(2) = 47$ (I am only changing the value at that one point).  When you take the IVT of the FT, you are not going to get a function $\check{\hat{f}}$ with $\check{\hat{f}}(2) = 47$.  Should I ask what happened to my $47$?

Comment: Yes, I finally got it. Thanks a lot for your patience. I didn't understand measure theory so I didn't realize that changing finite numbers of point will NOT change the FT spitt out function but won't get recovered either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the [Gibb's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon).  It is more thoroughly explained there, but the short version is:

- Not all functions are recovered by the inverse Fourier transform of their Fourier transform.
- The combination "inverse Fourier transform of the Fourier transform of $f(t)$" is a projection operator, onto some subset, $F_{\text{nice}}$, of the space of functions.
- The more times a function is continuously differentiable, the "closer" it is to $F_{\text{nice}}$ and the smaller the discrepancy between finite initial sums of "inverse Fourier transform of the Fourier transform of $f(t)$" and $f$.
- At jump discontinuities, the function isn't even zero times continuously differentiable, so we can expect larger changes in the projection.

These changes caused by a jump discontinuity, at $x = x_0$, say, are:

- The projection function outputs the midpoint of the jump at $x_0$.
- The projection function overshoots the height of the jump from both sides in an oscillatory manner.

For your function,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^-} f(t) &= 0  \text{ and }  \\
\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} f(t) &= 1  \text{.}  
\end{align*}
So we expect the inverse Fourier transform of the Fourier transform of $f$ to be a function having $f(0) = \frac{0+1}{2} = 1/2$.